# rails server side to upload file from jquery-html5-upload?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html

I'm trying to use this plugin: jquery-html5-upload http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-html5-upload
and it's working but i don't know how to get the file and save it on the server on the rails action.

in my rails log i just get this:

```
...
7?\021\b\000\034\000%\003\001\021\000\002\021\001\003\021\001\377?\e\000\000\001\005\001\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\003\001\002\004\005\006\000\a\377?2\020\000\001\002\002\b\005\002\004\a\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\001\002\003\004\021\000\005\022\023\024!\"1\006\#$2A\aQ\026ar?3BCR\201\243\261\377?\030\001\001\001\001\001\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\002\001\004\005\377?!\021\001\000\001\003\003\005\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\021\001\002\
...
```

i don't really know how to get the file and save it on the server.
thx.

Answer (score 0):

Use new version - it can upload files like usual form file uploading.
Or try to adapt PHP example from [link text](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-html5-upload/issues/detail?id=3&can=1)

Comment: I downloaded the latest version but how can i get the file with rack? with params[:file] or sth like dat?-